# Laravel use a custom validation message

Tags: php, laravel

I have made a custom rule in Laravel 5.5, but also want to get a custom translation with it from the lang validation file. For that I have now done:

```
'custom' => [
    'validate' => [
        'correct_password' => 'The :attribute is incorrect.',
    ],
],
```

And I put this in the custom rule file:

```
 return trans('validate.correct_password');
```

What have I done wrong to get the custom message? Because I get now only back the key: `validate.correct_password` as a message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to pull a key from the translation file, then you need to pass it a key path in the form of `file.key.subkey.subkey`.

```
return trans('validation.custom.validate.correct_password');
```